# How to hit url in javascript

Tags: javascript, url

I want to just hit the url in javascript which will run in background not on frontend.

I had tried [this code](http://www.neowin.net/forum/topic/575410-javascript-something-like-phps-curl-hit-a-web-page/)

```
var url = "http://yourpage.com";

req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

   req.open("GET", true);

   req.onreadystatechange = callback;

   req.send(null);
```

but it not work for me.

could any one please suggest me how to hit url in javascript.

Comment: The `req.open` line has unmatched double quotes.

Comment: Sorry by mistaken pressed 'l' instade of closeing the quote

Answer (score 2):

you should use cross browser JavaScript AJAX code, or better to use jQuery ajax see below sample code

```
    var url = "http://yourpage.com";
    var xmlhttp;

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = callback;

    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use either **jQuery** or **AngularJs** for sending AJAX requests rather than creating new ActiveXObject objects.

**Girish** gave you answer using pure javascript. I will give you an example of jQuery usage. Please see code below:

```
$.get('http://yourpage.com', function(){ /*callback*/ })
```